# Using Replace Function in Join (SQL)

Tags: sql, presto

I have two tables where in both tables there is a column `list_id`.I need to remove specific characters from this column from table2 in order make the join work. See example data below:

```
table1.list_id           table2.list_id
6353                      tb6353
3455                      tb3455 
5354                      tb5354
```

My query looks like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON REPLACE(table2.list_id,'tb','') = table1.list_id
```

However, when running this query in `Presto`, I get the following error: `'=' cannot be applied to varchar, bigint`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON CAST(REPLACE(table2.list_id,'tb','') AS bigint) = table1.list_id
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON REPLACE(table2.list_id,'tb','') = CAST(table1.list_id as VARCHAR)
```